# Is there a way to change the background color of the xcassets view in Xcode 5 or Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, configuration, background, asset-catalog, xcasset

Is there a way to change the background color of the xcassets view in Xcode 5 or Xcode 6?

I have white images that are lost on the white background.

When viewing an image without using xcassets, the image is set against a grey background.

However with xcassets the background is white and the images can't be seen.

I've tried using different different font and color schemes but they only seem to apply to the text editor.

Comment: it may be hidden somewhere in com.apple.dt.XCode

Comment: @PeterLapisu thanks for the tip. I dumped my current settings (in terminal: defaults read com.apple.dt.XCode > xcodeprefs.plist ) but was unable to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are happy to add an Xcode plugin (it's available via Alcatraz) then 
TOCAssetCatalogBackground solves this problem. https://github.com/toco/TOCAssetCatalogBackground

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me tons of hours for converting images!

Answer (score 13):

A reasonable work around is to select the image asset, (eg click on the 1x or 2x version) and then press the spacebar.
This will show the asset in a popover with a light grey background.

Comment: @Ixx - I was confused by your comment when I first saw it as the popover still has a very light grey background for me (Xcode 6.3.2). Then today while using an external monitor the same thing happened to me. It turns out that the external display wasn't calibrated properly. (try dragging the pop up from the external display to your laptop display).

Answer (score 3):

Are the images essentially silhouettes? If so, you could make them in another color (I like to use magenta, because then it’s immediately clear when something isn’t working). Then you can use iOS 7’s [`-[UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7) (not sure if there is a Mac equivalent) to have the image automatically pick up the tint color of its containing view. Then you would not be looking at white images on a white background.